# AngularFire seems to be deleting my objects on subsequent controller loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm using AngularFire in a multiplayer game and it sure looks like AngularFire is deleting my objects after the first load of a controller.

I'm using browserify to concatenate my JS files together so all my modules look like CommonJS modules.

My controllers are all loaded via `ngView`s and defined routes. I'm trying to keep knowledge of what user objects in Firebase look like confined to a user service; hence, all AngularFire invocations for the user object live in the service.

Here's my HomeController:

```
module.exports = function(ngModule) {
  ngModule.controller('HomeController',
      function($scope, user) {
    if (!$scope.user) {
      return;
    }

    user.getInvitations($scope);
    user.getGames($scope);
  });
};
```

I'm using AngularFire's auth from an auth service I defined. When the user object comes in, it is stored on the $rootScope. Here's a snippet of my auth service:

```
ngModule.run(function(angularFireAuth, warbase, $rootScope) {
  // Here's where Firebase does all the work.
  angularFireAuth.initialize(warbase, {
    scope: $rootScope,
    name: 'user',
    path: '/login'
  });
});
```

My user service uses a `gotUser` promise that is resolved when the user is present on the $rootScope. Here's a snippet of my user service:

```
$rootScope.$watch('user', function() {
  if (!$rootScope.user) {
    return;
  }
  userRef = warUsers.child(getPlayerId());
  userInvitationsRef = userRef.child('invitations');
  userGamesRef = userRef.child('games');
  gotUser.resolve();
});

// ...

getInvitations: function(scope) {
  scope.invitations = [];
  gotUser.promise.then(function() {
    angularFire(userInvitationsRef, scope, 'invitations');
  });
},

getGames: function(scope) {
  scope.games = [];
  gotUser.promise.then(function() {
    angularFire(userGamesRef, scope, 'games');
  });
}
```

When my HomeController is loaded by a user with no games and no invitations everything works as expected. The user creates a game and it shows up on the home screen.

If I then reload the page the user's game objects (from path `/users/:userId/games/`) are cleared. There is no code to remove these values in my application at the moment.

I thought there might be a reference to AngularFire hanging around and syncing the blank value I set in the user service, so I removed the `scope.games = [];` line. If I don't set the initial value on the scope in my service I get this error in the console: `Uncaught Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined`.

I'm guessing this has something to do with my unfamiliarity with controller lifecycles under `ngView`, my mis-use of services to DRY up my Firebase/AngularFire references, and general AngularJS newbishness all rolled into a galloping ball of fail, but I'd appreciate any pointers anyone can provide.

Comment: Sanity check here.  A controllers data gets cleared when you change controllers or reload the page.   Is this what is happening?

Comment: I'm seeing the data disappear from Firebase, the persistent store, only when the page is reloaded (brought back to its initial state). Navigating away from the page the scope is destroyed but the persistent data is, well... persisted. ( =

Comment: AngularFire will clear the data when the $scope is destroyed, we're debating adding an option that will allow developers to control this: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/pull/136

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Anant. Consider this a +1 for that option. ( = Any suggestions for a workaround until that lands? Is there a way to turn AngularFire off for a given scope? Maybe I should use Firebase directly until then?